# How to add css for a react-widget DropdownList?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to remove the border from a react-widget dropdownlist.

What I've tried;

**HTML**

```
<DropdownList
  data={this.props.create.repos}
  textField='key'
  placeholder={placeholder}
  className='dropdown_customized'
  onChange={this.props.save.bind(this, scenarioIndex, stepIndex, placeholder)}
  groupBy='name'
  filter='contains'
/>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown_customized {
    max-width: 200px !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

But since its creating a div outside the DropdownList the style is not getting applied.

Anyone know how to fix this??

*UPDATE*

The `displayInputBox` function returns the DropdownList..

```
<div className="flex-container">
   <span className="blueTag"> &emsp;&emsp; {step.stepOne} </span>
   <div className="divider" />
   {this.displayInputBox(this, step.stepTwo, step.stepId, item.scenarioId)}
</div>

   .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: stretch;
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the HTML resulting from this widget?

Comment: @Zenoo I've updated the question :)

Comment: I meant the end HTML result, when everything is already processed.

Comment: None of the styles are getting applied at all. Just showing the initial dropdownlist. But i will add a screenshot

Comment: I don't mean how it is displayed, I only need the final HTML code, which you can find by inspecting your element.

Comment: Alright my bad. I will add a screenshot of the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the DropdownList classes

```
.rw-widget-container{
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: But this would change the style for all the React-widget elements i have in the page.. I want this style applied only for a perticular div

Comment: try .dropdown_customized .rw-widget-container{
    border: none;
}